# Jackson Object mapper how to Serialize object as String which is having nested object?

Tags: jackson-databind

I have json like following

```
 {"data": [
        {
            "instance": { ... 
                          "inner"" {....
                                    .............}
                        }
         }]
 "isvalid":true
 "nextVal" : <some num>

}
```

and POJO like

```
class A{
    private String data;

    private boolean isvalid;

    private String nextVal;

//with getter setters and proper jackson annotations
}
```

These can have variable structure inside data, so with object mapper.read I want to take entire data object in string!

have tried direct serialization to my simple object which obviously gives error and also tried JSONNode

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
String content = node.get("data").textValue();
```

This returns blank

anyway I can achieve that to take entire data object value in string with objectmapper?

Comment: I am getting other two properties correct but not data one from JsonNode! data comes null only

Answer (score 0):

The reason it returns blank is because, `data` is an array. You need to deseralise it in to JsonArray. Assuming your JSON structure as below,

```
{
    "data": [
        {"instance": {
            "inner": {
                "id": "1"
            }
        }
    }],
    "isvalid": true,
    "nextVal": 1
}
```

This will be deserialised using below code (in JSONNode),

```
List<JsonNode> list = node.findValues("data");
        for(JsonNode n: list){
            JsonNode in1 = n.findValue("instance");
            JsonNode in2 = in1.findValue("inner");
            String abc =  in2.findValue("id").textValue();
            System.out.println(abc);
        }
```

You need to have the POJO structure as shown above. The `data` will be list of `instance` object. `instance` object will have to have `inner` object.

**Update:**

```
Outer node = mapper.readValue(jsonstr, Outer.class);
```

The classes which needs to be created would be as shown below.

```
public class Outer {
        private List<Data> data;
        Boolean valid;
        Integer nextval;

        public List<Data> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(List<Data> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Boolean isValid() {
            return valid;
        }

        public void setValid(Boolean valid) {
            this.valid = valid;
        }

        public Integer getNextval() {
            return nextval;
        }

        public void setNextval(Integer nextval) {
            this.nextval = nextval;
        }
    }


    public class Data {
         Instance instance;

        public Instance getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        public void setInstance(Instance instance) {
            this.instance = instance;
        }
    }

    public class Instance {
          private  Inner inner;

        public Inner getInner() {
            return inner;
        }

        public void setInner(Inner inner) {
            this.inner = inner;
        }
    }

    public class Inner {
            private String id;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is properties inside data can be variable so i cant create POJO for them! That's why I wanted to check if some way I can take entire data object to string.

Comment: In that case, you would need to use JsonNode. It will give you flexibility to search based on dynamic attribute names.

Comment: I tried   List<JsonNode> list = node.findValues("data");
   list.get(0).textValue()              is still null, I dont think textValue works well with non-string props  and also I am already using JsonNode!

Comment: ``list.get(0)`` will return you ``instance`` JSONNode but this JSONNode contains, another ``inner`` JSONNode. So ``textValue`` will not work there. If you want, the JSONNode as string, you need to use ``node.toString`` or ``node.toPrettyString()``

Comment: if its non-string like ``nextval``, you will need to do something like this ``node.findValue("nextVal").asInt()``

Comment: yes but I wanted data object entirely and dont want to go nested

Answer (score 0):

I tried toString and returned just fine what I wanted - entire data object as String

```
JsonNode node = (ObjectNode) mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
node.get("data").toString();
```